# Is there a way to determine which google play leaderboard api privacy setting the user has chosen?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-games, leaderboard

I am developing an android game in Unity 469. I am trying to come to terms with adding Google Play Leaderboards. My issue is that when requesting Player Centered Scores, I would like to retrieve the correct collection - the choice is between 'private' and 'public' leaderboards. If the user has chosen not to appear on public high score lists, the Player Centered Scores will not show up, but instead retrieve the top scores, unless I specifically ask for the non-public version. What I cannot seem to find is a way to beforehand read the user's Google Play Games privacy setting and get the right leaderboard immediately.

Best Regards
Jakob
Three Gates

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, there's no "private" leaderboards since there are only 2 types of it - social and public. Public leaderboard is self-explanatory. Social leaderboard, however, is a leaderboard based on members of the circle the user chose to share in the application. If its possible, I'll just suggest you create a solo circle of only the user in it and use social leaderboard.

In terms of knowing the user's privacy setting, it seems there's no way of looking at it based on the API references on Games API. [Player](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/Player) only has relevant games-related information.